# Cannot install tmap tmaptools, Error unable to load shared object lwgeom.so': libproj.so.19

Tags: r, linux, r-sf, tmap

I cannot install the R packages `tmaptools` and `tmap` in ubuntu linux, I have followed the instructions in

https://geocompr.github.io/post/2020/installing-r-spatial-ubuntu/

I installed `sf` and checked:

```
library(sf)
Linking to GEOS 3.10.1, GDAL 3.4.0, PROJ 8.2.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
Warning messages:
1: replacing previous import ‘lifecycle::last_warnings’ by ‘rlang::last_warnings’ when loading ‘pillar’ 
2: replacing previous import ‘lifecycle::last_warnings’ by ‘rlang::last_warnings’ when loading ‘tibble’
```

When I try to instal `tmaptools` the following error appears

```
> install.packages("tmaptools")
Installing package into ‘/home/leonardo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/tmaptools_3.1-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 40116 bytes (39 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 39 KB

* installing *source* package ‘tmaptools’ ...
** package ‘tmaptools’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Warning: replacing previous import ‘lifecycle::last_warnings’ by ‘rlang::last_warnings’ when loading ‘pillar’
Warning: replacing previous import ‘lifecycle::last_warnings’ by ‘rlang::last_warnings’ when loading ‘tibble’
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/home/leonardo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/lwgeom/libs/lwgeom.so':
  libproj.so.19: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Calls: <Anonymous> ... asNamespace -> loadNamespace -> library.dynam -> dyn.load
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘tmaptools’
* removing ‘/home/leonardo/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/tmaptools’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tmaptools’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have already removed the package and installed it again, but I always get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Browsing the tmap issues on github I found the answer:

install lwgeom package, so

```
install.packages("lwgeom")
```

Solved the problem.